# search forward slashes in a string in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, regular-expressions

i want to replace a string after it matches a series of forward slashes till end of the line in a lightning component but the regex won't work.

ex - the string value: // this is an example.

I want to replace this whole line and I am using the below regex but it doesn't work at all:

```
const regex = /^\\/\\/\*.\*$/m;
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your double-backslashes would be interpreted as single backslashes. I think you meant:

```
const regex = /\/{2}.*$/m;
```

Note that I suggest removing the `^`, since it would only match the entire line, but I believe you're trying to match just the `//` to the end of the line?